# msbuild error with /win32icon parameter in vbc.exe

Tags: vb.net, msbuild

I try to compile a project with msbuild.exe

I have this error :

```
vbc : error BC30136: Error creating Win32 resources: Error reading icon '"Recycle Bin Empty.ico"' -- The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

This icon is the Application icon which is in the same directory of the project.

vbc is started with `/win32icon:"Recycle Bin Empty.ico"` parameter.
Don't know why MSBuild can't reach the file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things to try

- Remove the spaces in the file name. Will eliminate any quoting issues
- Pass the fully qualified path to the file name. Will eliminate any relative path issues

Comment: MSBuild launch vbc.exe himself.
But I try to remove spaces.